# Data truncation: Incorrect date value:

Tags: mysql

```
 INSERT INTO INSTRUCTORBOOKING (INSTRUCTORID, TIMESLOT, STATUS, DATE)
 VALUES('', '8.00 - 9.00', 'Free', 'Sun Jan 08 00:00:00 CST 2012')
```

Basically when I run it it gives me this error:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date 
 value: 'Sun Jan 08 00:00:00 CST 2012' for column 'Date' at row 1
```

the Date column is of type Date. The Value for date also came from one of my previous questions, but its a Date object. Appreciate the help so far!!

Comment: The value, *Sun Jan 08 00:00:00 CST 2012'*, you are inserting is not a valid date format. I strongly suggest, *even if your values are set internally*, to use `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO INSTRUCTORBOOKING (INSTRUCTORID, TIMESLOT, STATUS, DATE)
 VALUES('', '8.00 - 9.00', 'Free', '2012-01-08 00:00:00')
```